# Vulkan Storage Buffer Memory Mapping

Tags: c++, vulkan, moltenvk

I'm refactoring and re-writing the guide made by [VkGuide](https://vkguide.dev/) as to fit my idea of an engine. I'm using [VMA](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/VulkanMemoryAllocator) to handle my memory needs.

I've stumbled upon a strange (?) issue in refactoring my memory mapping code into something more easily readable:

Original code:

```
Renderer fields

//-------------------------------------------------

struct ObjectData { matrix4 transform };

inline Frame& frame(); // Get current frame in flight

std::vector<RenderableObject> renderables;

//--------------------------------------------------

Drawing code

void* object_data;
vmaMapMemory(allocator, frame().object_buffer.allocation, &object_data);
auto* ssbo = static_cast<ObjectData*>(object_data);
for (int i = 0; i < renderables.size(); i++) {
    auto& object = renderables[i];
    ssbo[i].model_matrix = object.transform;
}
vmaUnmapMemory(allocator, frame().object_buffer.allocation)
```

and the refactored and templated namespace-local function:

```
struct AllocatedBuffer { VkBuffer buffer, VmaAllocation allocation }; 

template <typename T, typename Func>
void effect_mmap(VmaAllocator& allocator, AllocatedBuffer& buffer, Func&& effect)
{
    void* object_data;
    vmaMapMemory(allocator, buffer.allocation, &object_data);
    auto* t_pointer = static_cast<T*>(object_data);
    effect(*t_pointer);
    vmaUnmapMemory(allocator, buffer.allocation);
}
```

My camera position and everything else seems to shift and work incorrectly. Following shows usage (which now should replace the original code):

```
MemoryMapper::effect_mmap<ObjectData>(allocator, frame().object_buffer, [&](ObjectData& data) {
    for (auto& object : renderables) {
        data.model_matrix = object.transform;
    }
});
```

and here are the correct (the textures are still invalid, and I don't know why, that's for another day) and afters: [Correct, and Incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlWhW.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage example only ever sets the *first* SSBO in the buffer, as `data` is `*t_pointer` and never changes.
Change your code to pass `t_pointer` directly, change the type of the callback and then you can use it as

```
MemoryMapper::effect_mmap<ObjectData>(allocator, frame().object_buffer, [&](ObjectData* data) {
    for (auto& object : renderables) {
        data->model_matrix = object.transform;
        data++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Refactoring can sometimes be blinding. Pretty terrible design to force user to advance pointer though. Might rewrite.

Comment: That was just laziness on my behalf. Could go the `data[i].model_matrix = ...` route as well.

Comment: No, I meant on my part! Sorry, did really not mean to berate you! :(